# update django database to reflect changes in existing models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've already defined a model and created its associated database via `manager.py syncdb`. Now that I've added some fields to the model, I tried `syncdb` again, but no output appears. Upon trying to access these new fields from my templates, I get a "No Such Column" exception, leading me to believe that syncdb didn't actually update the database. What's the right command here?

Comment: You should change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Seems like what you need is a migration system. [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) is really nice, working great, has some automation tools to ease your workflow. And has a great [tutorial](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Tutorial1).

---

note: syncdb can't update your existing tables. Sometimes it's impossible to decide what to do automagicly - that's why south scripts are this great.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this interesting tool. For anyone interested, there's a insightful discussion about django database migration here:
http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SchemaEvolution

Comment: The link of South shows, "South has been deprecated. From Django 1.7 upwards, migrations are built into the core of Django. If you are running a previous version, you can find the repository on BitBucket.". So... what now?

Comment: links in the answer are broken

Answer (score 139):

> As of Django 1.7+, built-in [migrations support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/), allows for database schema migrations that preserve data. That's probably a better approach than the solution below.

Another option, not requiring additional apps, is to use the built in `manage.py` functions to export your data, clear the database and restore the exported data.

The methods below will update the database tables for your app, but will **completely destroy** any data that existed in those tables. If the changes you made to your app model do not break your old schema (for instance, you added a new, optional field) you can simply dump the data before and reload it afterwards, like so:

## Django 1.4.15 and earlier

```
python manage.py dumpdata <your_app> > temp_data.json
python manage.py reset <your_app>
python manage.py loaddata temp_data.json
```

## Django 1.5 and newer

```
python manage.py dumpdata <your_app> > temp_data.json
python manage.py sqlclear <your_app> | python manage.py dbshell
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py loaddata temp_data.json
```

(The `reset` command was deprecated and then removed in [Django 1.5](https://github.com/django/django/commit/d38690796cd5c046c0b141174737b7615c143bb1))

If your changes break your old schema this won't work - in which case tools like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) or [Django Evolution](https://github.com/beanbaginc/django-evolution) are great.

Comment: I think this solution is best.

Comment: +1 like to use some thing that is already in django without any other django app. required

Comment: For django 1.5.1 users: manage.py reset is no longer supported.  The flush can be used to delete everything. You can also use ALTER TABLE or DROP TABLE statements manually (from django ref): python manage.py flush

Comment: if I add field is ManyToManyField,
the Error: Unable to serialize database: (1146, "Table 'gavacafe.subject_subject_vote_users' doesn't exist")

Comment: In Django 1.7, you can do this with native `migrations`

Answer (score 45):

As of Django 1.7, you can now do this with native migrations. Just run

```
python manage.py makemigrations <your app name>
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 9):

Django's syncdb doesn't alter existing tables in the database so you have to do it manually. The way I always do it is:

1. Change the model class first.
2. Then run: manage.py sql myapp.
3. Look at the sql it prints out and see how it represented the change you are going to make.
4. Make the change manually using your database manager.
5. Check to see if everything worked correctly using the admin site.

If you are using sqllite a good manager is the firefox plugin: [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817)

Comment: I actually think this is the best and easiest solution

Answer (score 8):

Another tool would be django evolution. No table dropping needed in most cases.

[django evolution](http://code.google.com/p/django-evolution/)

Just install it as any other django app and run:

python manage.py evolve --hint --execute

Answer (score 3):

[deseb](http://code.google.com/p/deseb/) is a great tool for that.

Having it installed, you can write ./manage.py sqlevolve and it'll generate sql commands necessary to keep the database structure in sync with your models.

Comment: This looks like what I needed. Does sqlevolve commit the changes as well?

Comment: Sadly unusably dated now :-(

Comment: @BerndWechner I used to support it (in my own fork) for quite a long time, but `makemigrations` got better and better and nowadays it is the way to go with schema migrations.

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop your tables before you can recreate them with `syncdb`.

If you want to preserve your existing data, then you need to unload your database,
drop your tables, run `syncdb` to build a new database, then reload your old data into your new tables.

There are tools that help with this.  However, in many cases, it's just as easy to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

For versions 1.4.1 and above users the command has changed to

```
python manage.py flush
```

Please read the [official document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/faq/models/#if-i-make-changes-to-a-model-how-do-i-update-the-database) before using it as **it will delete all your data**.

Comment: What I don't understand is flush actually resets the database as it was after `syncdb` was executed, but what about the potentially newly added fields ? They don't get created