# Django : unknown application

Tags: database, django, dump, django-apps

I want to dump my data from the model of my app in Django.

So I tried the following `python manage.py dumpdata app > temp_data.json` (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985383/update-django-database-to-reflect-changes-in-existing-models/1992512#1992512))

where "app" is an app I created via `python manage.py startapp app`

It throws me the following error :

```
Error: Unknown application: asset
```

Can someone help me to figure out what's going on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the app listed in your settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS?