# Manage.py sqlall <myapp> does not create column

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I added `orgname = models.CharField(max_length=50)` to my an existing class in my models.py and I ran `python manage.py syncdb` but figured out that it doesn't create columns (I'm using PostgreSQL by the way), so I needed to do `python manage.py sqlall <myapp>` which I did and it outputted the following:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "file_uploader_files" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "file" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "orgname" varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
;
COMMIT;
```

Yet, when I go into the shell for Django or look in pgAdmin3, the column is still not created. What am I doing wrong? I'd add it manually but I'm not sure how.

P.S. The table was already created before hand and so was the file varchar, orgname came after I initial made that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also see this SO question: [update django database to reflect changes in existing models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985383/update-django-database-to-reflect-changes-in-existing-models) (the top two answers cover your question).

From the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1985409/1431750):

> note: syncdb can't update your existing tables. Sometimes it's impossible to decide what to do automagicly - that's why south scripts are this great.

And in the other [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992512/1431750)...

> ```
> python manage.py reset <your_app>
> ```
>
> This will update the database tables for your app, but will completely destroy any data that existed in those tables.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the [`sqlall command`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#sqlall-appname-appname) says:

> Prints the CREATE TABLE and initial-data SQL statements for the given app name(s).

It prints the SQL, it doesn't run anything. Django will never modify your schema, you'll need to do it yourself - the output above can help by showing you the type of the orgname field. Or use something like South.

Comment: It's saying the column is already created in the table (in PgAdmin3 when I attempt to add the column myself) yet I can't find it anywhere and it doesn't show up in PgAdmin3. Thanks for the help by the way.