# Django PSQL table cannot be dropped

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I am having trouble deleting a table from a psql database. I tried the solution over at the following thread, but it would not work for me.

[update django database to reflect changes in existing models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985383/update-django-database-to-reflect-changes-in-existing-models)

The \d command results in the following

> List of relations
>    Schema |               Name                |   Type   | Owner  
>   --------+-----------------------------------+----------+--------
>    public | auth_group                        | table    | django
>    public | auth_group_id_seq                 | sequence | django
>    public | auth_group_permissions            | table    | django
>    public | auth_group_permissions_id_seq     | sequence | django
>    public | auth_permission                   | table    | django
>    public | auth_permission_id_seq            | sequence | django
>    public | auth_user                         | table    | django
>    public | auth_user_groups                  | table    | django
>    public | auth_user_groups_id_seq           | sequence | django
>    public | auth_user_id_seq                  | sequence | django
>    public | auth_user_user_permissions        | table    | django
>    public | auth_user_user_permissions_id_seq | sequence | django
>    public | django_admin_log                  | table    | django
>    public | django_admin_log_id_seq           | sequence | django
>    public | django_content_type               | table    | django
>    public | django_content_type_id_seq        | sequence | django
>    public | django_session                    | table    | django
>    public | kensoDataStore_tick               | table    | django
>    public | kensoDataStore_tick_id_seq        | sequence | django
>   (19 rows)

However, attempting to DROP TABLE kensoDataStore_tick; will result in the following:

ERROR:  table "kensodatastore_tick" does not exist

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Due to historic reasons, names in SQL are case-insensitive. To make it case sensitive you should quote it.

```
DROP TABLE "kensoDataStore_tick";
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!